# How to compile many JS and CSS files into one big JS and CSS file?

Tags: javascript, compilation

I have many js and css files. Is there any simple utility to compile them into two files?

```
util --input_dir=js/ --output=build.js

util --input_dir=css/ --output=build.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gulp or grunt for that.

http://gulpjs.com

http://gruntjs.com

Comment: Or if you prefer an interface you can look up codekit or prepros.

https://incident57.com/codekit/
https://prepros.io

Answer (score 2):

On linux you can use simple shell script https://github.com/dfsq/compressJS.sh to combine multiple javascript files into the single one. It makes use of the Closure Compiler online service so the resulting script is also effectively compressed.

```
$ ./compressJS.sh some-script.js another-sctipt.js onemore.js
```

You can also see: https://github.com/eloone/mergejs.

Second approach is to load them in parallel using: http://yepnopejs.com/ or http://headjs.com